# Read Avro file with python to create a SQL table

Tags: python, sql, avro, apache-nifi, create-table

I'm trying to create an SQL table from AVRO file which contains the structure of my table :

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "warranty",
  "doc" : "Schema generated by Kite",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1'"
  }, {
    "name" : "train_id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '21691'"
  }, {
    "name" : "siemens_nr",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Loco-001'"
  }, {
    "name" : "uic_nr",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '193901'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Configuration",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'ZP28'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Warranty_Status",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Out_of_Warranty'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Warranty_Data_Type",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Real_based_on_preliminary_acceptance_date'"
  }, {
    "name" : "of_progression",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '100'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Delivery_Date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '18/12/2009'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Warranty_on_Delivery_Date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '18/12/2013'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Customer_Status",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'homologation'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Commissioning_Date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '6/10/2010'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Preliminary_acceptance_date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '6/01/2011'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Warranty_Start_Date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '6/01/2011'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Warranty_End_Date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '6/01/2013'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Effective_End_Warranty_Date",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'null'",
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "Level_2_in_function",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '17/07/2015'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Baseline",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '2.10.23.4'"
  }, {
    "name" : "TC_report",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'A480140'"
  }, {
    "name" : "Last_version_Date",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'A-23/09/2015'"
  } ]
}
```

to do this job, I'm using ( if you have other proposition more simple it will be great)

so using python I will get a result like this :

```
{'name':'id',type':'long','doc':'blablabla'}
```

My question is how can I create an SQL table in python from this result?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You need to build an SQL command as a string, based on your structure description, then connect to database, then execute the statement. Which part do you need help with?

Comment: but i need to create this sql command from schema avro generated

Answer (score -1):

Using json module you can get a dict from your string, then you have an array of field definitions. You iterate through that array to make the SQL statement.

Note: you will need some mechanism for mapping avro field types to SQL field types, especially if you have types like `"type" : [ "null", "string" ]`.

Here is a working example of code building SQL CREATE TABLE statement based on your string:

```
import json

schema_str = """{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "warranty",
  "doc" : "Schema generated by Kite",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '1'"
  }, {
    "name" : "train_id",
    "type" : "long",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '21691'"
  }, {
    "name" : "siemens_nr",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from 'Loco-001'"
  } ]
}"""

schema = json.loads(schema_str)
fields =  schema['fields']

sql_string = 'CREATE TABLE ' + schema['name'] + ' ( \n'
for field in fields : 
    sql_string = sql_string + field['name'] + ' ' + field['type'] + ', \n'

sql_string = sql_string[:-3] + '\n)'  # get rid of last comma and close the field list

print sql_string
```